# 'matrix' plot with conditional formatting based on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i am looking for help on the following: given a dataframe i would like to display a 'matrix' plot whose values correspond to a pair in the table but are formatted according to the 'heatmap' of values of a different column corresponding to that pair. here is example data:

```
df_list = [('nyc', 'lax', 10,-10, -2,2),('nyc', 'chi', -9,9, -2,2),('nyc', 'sfo', -4,4,-1,1),('nyc', 'mia', 2,-2, 2,-2),('lax', 'chi', 5,-5, 1,-1),('lax', 'sfo', -8,8, 2,-2),
           ('lax', 'mia', -6,6,0,0),('chi', 'sfo', 9,-9, -1,1),('chi', 'mia', 1,-1,3,-3),('sfo', 'mia', -3,3, -2,2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=['x', 'y','x-y','y-x','num1','num2'])
```

so in excel, the unformatted result could look like this displaying the values in the 'x-y' (lower triangular) and 'y-x' (upper triangular) columns

[image]

but, what i would want in python is the cells to format according to the distribution of values in the 'num1' (lower triangular) or 'num2' (upper triangular) column

i want to achieve the color formatting below (which is based on the num1/num2 values, but i want the values displayed in the cells to correspond to the matrix above

[image]

i am aware of the seaborn heatmap functionality but i cannot find a suggestion to account for the difference between the display variable and the formatting variable. any advice or example would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one should divide the problem into two parts. The first would be, given the data in column form, how to obtain the respective correlation matrices. We need one for x-y/y-x (called `p` in below code) , and another for num1/num2 (called `n` in below code). Since the two columns are just of opposite signs, we may simplify things a bit such that the upper triagonal is just minus the lower one for both cases. Once this is done, the problem is of visualization is indeed a single line using `seaborn.heatmap`.

```
sns.heatmap(n, annot = p)
```

Complete example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_list = [('nyc', 'lax', 10,-10, -2,2),('nyc','chi',-9,9,-2,2),('nyc', 'sfo',-4,4,-1,1),
           ('nyc', 'mia', 2,-2, 2,-2),('lax','chi',5,-5,1,-1),('lax', 'sfo', -8,8, 2,-2),
           ('lax', 'mia', -6,6,0,0),('chi', 'sfo', 9,-9, -1,1),('chi', 'mia', 1,-1,3,-3),
           ('sfo', 'mia', -3,3, -2,2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=['x', 'y','x-y','y-x','num1','num2'])

u = np.unique(df[["x","y"]].values)

p1 = df.pivot("y","x","x-y").reindex(u,u)
p2 = df.pivot("x","y","x-y").reindex(u,u) 
p = p1.combine_first(p2)
utri = np.triu(np.ones(p.shape)).astype(np.bool)
p.values[utri] = -p.values[utri]

n1 = df.pivot("y","x","num1").reindex(u,u)
n2 = df.pivot("x","y","num1").reindex(u,u) 
n = n1.combine_first(n2)
n.values[utri] = -n.values[utri]

# color according to n, labels according to p
sns.heatmap(n, annot = p, center=0, cmap="RdBu")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this is a very elegant answer, but i just noticed an issue with my original post. consider these two examples:

1) row = nyc / col = lax: +10
2) row = sfo / col = chi: +9 

my intent was to present these values as "nyc-lax" and "sfo-chi" which based on my dataframe construction would reflect either "y-x" or "x-y", which would not be captured here correctly (my fault)

so, i think the correct approach on my end would have been to use a dataframe that had the full permuations as given and then not to have to worry about the -1* lower triangle and combine/pivot accordingly

Comment: Using the lower/upper triangle is only a shortcut here. If the correlation is not symmetric you need to create the pivots for `"y-x"` and `num2` as well and fill the upper triangle of `p` and `n` with the values from those pivots instead of the inverted values from themselves. Starting off with a dataframe with only the `x-y` and `num1` column, but with all possible permutations in the first two columns is of course equally possible.